# System upgrade kills Tex

Tags: latex

After a system upgrade, when I attempt to use LaTeX, I get the following error from within my compiler (TexMaker). I have no idea what it means. What should I do? (I did not set up TeX on the computer in the first place and don't know how to do that; I know how to open the terminal and do a few simple things but other than that am in over my head.)

> Process started
>
> warning: kpathsea: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R. warning: kpathsea: /usr/share/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
>
> warning: kpathsea: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R. kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
>
> warning: kpathsea: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
>
> warning: kpathsea: /usr/share/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R. warning: kpathsea: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
>
> tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
>
> Process exited with error(s)

Comment: Try running `sudo texhash`, it *might* fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This morning, I experienced the *same* problem.  Thanks to Luis de Sousa's answer (`sudo texhash`), I am now able to use LaTeX again.  I'm posting some screenshots to justify his comment.

## Background (TL;DR)

I had TeXLive properly installed on Xubuntu 18.04.  The command `dpkg -l tex*` showed `tex-common`, `texlive-xetex`, etc.

## Problem

Same as OP's problem.

[image: LaTeX error]

## After `sudo texhash`

The problem has gone.

[image: LaTeX compiled]